# Examples of "self-referential" sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, recurrence-relations, big-list, online-resources

I recently found the so-called [Van Eck's sequence](http://oeis.org/A181391), in which $a(n)$ is the answer to the question "except for $a_{n-1}$ itself, how far back did we last see $a_{n-1}$?" ($a_n=0$ if $ a_{n-1}$ never appeared before):

$$0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 6, 0, 5, 0, 2, 6, 5, 4, 0, 5, 3, 0, 3, 2, 9, 0, 4, 9, 3, 6, 14, 0, 6, 3, 5,\dots$$

I'm intrigued by the idea that the sequence is created by considering a feature of the sequence itself - it is self-referential in a funny way, almost circularly defined. I'm having a hard time pinning down this characteristic precisely, so forgive me the vagueness of the question:

> What are some examples of other such "self-referential" sequences?

I tried creating some myself, but they turned out to be not very interesting. For instance, "$a_n$ is the number of sub-sequences in $(a)_1^{n-1}$ that are $a_{n-1}$ long" is just $1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,\dots$

Homemade sequences are also very welcome!

---

*Edit:* I just found [the look-and-say sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-and-say_sequence), which is also rather neat:

$$1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, 312211, 13112221,\dots,$$
which is constructed by enumerating the number of certain numbers in a row found in the previous entry, i.e., the second entry is "one $1 =11$", the third is "two $1$s $=21$", etc.

Comment: This statement that I am making is a good example of a self-referential statement.

Comment: @Michael If only it was a sequence!

Comment: The first statement I made was self-referential but so is this second one.

Comment: The second statement I made was self-referential but so is this third one.

Comment: And so on and so on.

Comment: for my small understanding, could you please tell why it is fundamentally different from a sequence defined , for example , by the mean of the 4 previous elements ? TY very much

Comment: @igael It may not be, which is why I wrote that I'm having a hard time pinning down the quality I'm talking about - it just has a certain "flavor". But w.r.t. your example, the sequences I'm talking about are probably not linear.

Comment: @Lovsovs: here is a hand-made sequence. I didn't find it on OEIS! Start with $x_1=2$, say. Then $x_{n+1} = |\{i \in \{1,\dots,n-1\} \;:\; x_i=x_n\}|$ i.e. number of times you see $x_n$ in $\{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$. For instance: 2,0,0,1,0,2,1,1,2,2,3,0,3,1…

Comment: @Watson Great, please do post it as an answer! :)

Comment: Look up the [Kolakoski sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolakoski_sequence).

Comment: [Thue-Morse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence)

Comment: @bof Please do post as an answer! (Preferably with a short description and a link to the similar Gijswijt's sequence.)

Comment: @Winther Please do post as an answer! (Preferably with a short description.)

Answer (score 6):

$$1, 2,2, 1,1, 2,1, 2,2,1, 2,2,1,1,2, 1,1,2,2,1,2,1, 2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,2, 1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2\dots$$
The [Kolakoski sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolakoski_sequence) (OEIS sequence [A000002](https://oeis.org/A000002)) is the infinite sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,\dots$ of ones and twos consisting of a block of $a_1$ ones followed by a block of $a_2$ twos, then $a_3$ ones, $a_4$ twos, $a_5$ ones, and so on. It is [an unproven conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolakoski_sequence#Density) that the sequence contains equal proportions of ones and twos, i.e., that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}n=1.5$$
Another unproven conjecture is that the finite subwords of the Kolakoski sequence can be characterized as the so-called $C^\infty$-words; see
[William D. Weakley, On the number of $C^\infty$-words of each length, Journal of Combinatorial Theory Serie A 51 (1989), 55–62](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0097316589900769/1-s2.0-0097316589900769-main.pdf?_tid=a75e7dfc-7932-11e6-a810-00000aab0f02&acdnat=1473717094_9f4acf28400df1d97c51382e66aea8e0)
and
[Yun Bao Huang and William D. Weakley, A note on the complexity of $C^\infty$-words, Theoretical Computer Science 411 (2010), 3731–3735](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397510003580).

Answer (score 5):

[Hofstadter Sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter_sequence) include "Fibonacci-like" examples such as
$$
G(n) = n - G(G(n-1))\, ,
$$
where the term needed to calculate the current value is found by counting back a number of steps equal to the previous value.

Comment: Given your explanation, did you mean to say "G(n)=G(n-G(n-1))"?

Answer (score 5):

Sequences can be self-referential in a *multitude* of ways, and OEIS contains examples for quite a few of them. We're barely scratching the surface.

Can't believe nobody mentioned the [Golomb's sequence](https://oeis.org/A001462): $a_n$ is the number of times $n$ occurs. It has relatively calm and ordered (that is, not chaotic) demeanor, but a peculiar growth order: $O(n^{\varphi-1})$. There are some links to related sequences, too.

Also, look at [this little gem](https://oeis.org/A239281): $a_{n+1}=a_c+1$, where $c$ is the number of times $a_n$ appeared among the previous terms. It is unbounded, but grows mighty slowly (though admittedly not as slowly as [Gijswijt's](https://oeis.org/A090822), you can't beat that).

Comment: Very interesting examples, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a home-made sequence. I didn't find it on OEIS! Start with $x_1=2$, say. Then define $$x_{n+1} = |\{i \in \{1,\dots,n-1\} \;:\; x_i=x_n\}|$$ i.e. the number of times you see $x_n$ in $\{x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}\}$.
For instance, you get: $$2,0,0,1,0,2,1,1,2,2,3,0,3,1,…$$

---

Starting with $x_1=1$, you get $$1,0,0,1,1,2,0,2,1,3,0,3,1,4,0,4,1,…,n,0,n,1,…$$
and with $x_1=2$, you get 
$$2,0,0,1,0,2,1,1,2,2,3,0,3,1,3,2,\; 4,0,4,1,4,2,\; 5,0,5,1,5,2,\;…,\; n,0,n,1,n,2, \; n+1,0,n+1,1,n+1,2, \;…$$

Starting with some $x_1 ≥ 1$ yields a sequence with the pattern $n,0,n,1,n,2,…,n,x_1$.

Comment: Do you have a Mathematica script for producing it? I tried `f[n_] := Count[Table[f[n - 1], {n, 1, n - 2}], f[n - 1]]`, but that didn't work (I would have been surprised if it did, 'cause I never tried to define a recursive function in Mathematica before).

Comment: @Lovsovs: ahah, I was just trying to produce such a Mathematica script... without any success for now!

Comment: Hehe, I guess it is the natural thing to do when spotting a sequence! I'm also trying to make `RecurrenceTable` work. Let me know if you find anything!

Comment: Will do! $\;\;\;{}$

Comment: All right, I asked a question at Mathematica SE, will report back.

Comment: Here it is: `f[1] = 2;
f[n_] := Count[Table[f[k - 1], {k, 2, n - 1}], f[n - 1]];
Table[f[n], {n, 1, 20}]`! But it takes an *extreme* amount of power/time to calculate it!

Comment: Try playing with some different seed-values.. Some really funny behaviour!

Comment: @Lovsovs Start the definition with `f[n_]:=f[n]=...`; in such a way it will remember what it did for $n-1$ and will use it for computing $f(n)$. E.g., up to $n=1000$ in 0.25 sec on my laptop.

Comment: @corey979 Fantastic, thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/v4Z6XXK) is an animation of the sequence for different values of $k\in(0,50)$ (which is $x(1)$, i.e., the seed).

Answer (score 3):

[Aronson's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aronson%27s_sequence). Quoting from Wikipedia,

Aronson's sequence is an integer sequence defined by the English sentence "T is the first, fourth, eleventh, sixteenth, ... letter in this sentence." Spaces and punctuation are ignored. The first few numbers in the sequence are:

1, 4, 11, 16, 24, 29, 33, 35, 39, 45, 47, 51, 56, 58, 62, 64, 69, 73, 78, 80, 84, 89, 94, 99, 104, 111, 116, 122, 126, 131, 136, 142, 147, 158, 164, 169, ... (sequence [A005224](https://oeis.org/A005224) in the OEIS).

There's more discussion at the Wikipedia page, with links to related sequences.

Answer (score 0):

**Fibonacci Sequence** is self-referential:

> F(n) = F(n-2) + F(n-1)
>
> ...and is grounded with the definitions of the first two numbers:
>
> F(0) = 0
>
> F(1) = 1

0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, ...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

https://oeis.org/A000045

---

**Leonardo numbers**, related, are self-referential:

> a(n) = a(n-1) + a(n-2) + 1
>
> ...and is grounded with the definitions of the first two numbers:
>
> a(0) = 1
>
> a(1) = 1

1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 25, 41, 67, 109, 177, 287, ...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_number

https://oeis.org/A001595